# Can we add cities list without module in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2

I am looking to add the cities list for the India in `magento 2.x` by custom js. Like storing cities list in array. when the state field is selected

for example :-

> Maharashtra I want to display its cities by storing the cities in
>   array. Can that be achieved.

I am unable to find any `free extension` to implement city dropdown.

Comment: Please let me know which is the best possible way to achieve the indian cities list dropdown.

Comment: You can use this extension : https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

Comment: @Sneha Panchal Can I install it without using composer?.

Comment: @Sneha Panchal How to restrict a product availability to a particular city. like organic product available only to delhi and its not available to outside delhi.

Comment: yes it can install without using composer